# Find a sequence such that $a_n^2=(a_{n-1}^2+a_{n+1}^2)/2$ for $n=2,3,\ldots$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Suppose $a_n \in \mathbb{N}$ are natural numbers such that: 
$$a_n^2=\frac{a_{n-1}^2+a_{n+1}^2}{2}\quad  (n=2,3,\ldots), \quad a_1=10 $$
Find  $a_n$

*Progress*: So far I had come up with $a_n^2=100+(n-1)(a_2^2-100)$ result.

Comment: I had come up with $a_n^2=100+(n-1)(a_2^2-100)$ result

Comment: $a_n = 10$, what you need to show is this is the only solution such that $a_n \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : If $b_{n} = a_{n}^{2}$, then you have
$$b_{n+1} - 2\,b_{n} + b_{n-1} = 0$$
which is a second order recurrence

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's denote $d=a_2^2-100$. Thus our $a_n^2$ is an arithmetic progression with common difference of $d$. Can it be infinite? Obviously, $d$ can't be negative, otherwise at some point the terms will become negative, which is bad for squares. Can it be positive, then? Suppose it can; this would lead to unbounded growth of $a_n^2$. At some point it will exceed $d^2$. But wait; with numbers that big, the difference of two squares is at least $2d+1$ (that is, if they are adjacent; otherwise even more). Can we still continue our sequence with squares which are exactly $d$ apart? No, we can't.

This leaves the only possibility of $d=0$ and $a_n=10$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest considering your equation as a recurrence relation and try substituting, $a_n=Ar^n$. Then you will get, $r=\pm 1$ and therefore you have the general solution as,

$$a_n=A+B(-1)^{n}$$

for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: We can't do that with $a_n$, because we don't have the **linear** recurrence relation for $a_n$. We have one for $a_n^2$, but its characteristic equation roots are not $\pm1$, just $+1$ (twice).